# What are the rules on using a pair of locked gauntlets?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, equipment, two-weapon-fighting

My dual wielding character just got disarmed without being able to retrieve his weapons because they fell into a pit. Suddenly the most capable fighter of the party became a waste of space.

So I wondered whether acquiring locked gauntlets would help preventing such misfortune in the future. But then I imagined how you put them on. In real life it would be next to impossible locking two swords to your hands. Thus my question: what are the rules on using two locked gauntlets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only rules about *Locked Gauntlet* are that:

- It takes a *Full Round Action*, provoking an *Attack of Opportunity*, to lock or unlock the *Gauntlet*.
- You cannot use the hand wearing the *Locked Gauntlet* for casting spells or employing skills.

Therefore, it is DM territory whether a single character, with only two-hands, could by themselves lock and unlock a Locked Gauntlet on each hand. It seems reasonable, though, to derive from the second point that they couldn't.

Note that even if they actually could, it would take them **2 rounds** to actually lock and unlock both gauntlets, which is just too prohibitive to be considered in combat.

This leaves such a character with the unpalatable option of locking both gauntlets ahead of time and walking around with weapons drawn:

- Unsuitable for civilized settings.
- Drastically limiting the character's option: no opening door, picking up objects, climbing that wall, ...

A homebrew, auto-locking, gauntlet is a potential solution, at the discretion of the DM.

---

Beyond *Locked Gauntlets*, there are some alternatives.

**Crystal of Security**

The Magic Item Compendium introduces *Augment Crystals* (p. 221). The gist of it is that you can attach *one* crystal to a weapon at a time, and the more potent the weapon, the more potent the crystal you are allowed to attach: Least requires masterwork weapons, Lesser +1 weapons and Greater +3 weapons.

To avoid being disarmed, the various *Crystal of Security* (MIC, p. 65) give among other bonuses:

- Least, 300 gp: +2.
- Lesser, 1,000 gp: +5.
- Greater, 3,000 gp: +10.

It's not cheap (3,000 gp is way more than a Locked Gauntlet), but it comes with none of the issues about taking time to lock/unlock. And it stacks, should you wish to go down that road.

**Crystal of Return**

If you actually get disarmed regardless, being able to summon your weapon to hand is always handy. A *Crystal of Return, Lesser* (MIC, p. 65; 1,000 gp):

> As the Least crystal, and in addition you can call the weapon (if unattended)
> to your hand from up to 30 feet away as a Move Action.

It may not have worked in your specific case, depending on deep the pit is, and it may not work in cases where you fly/swim.

**Called Armor/Shield Enhancement**

The *Called* Armor/Shield Enhancement (MIC, p. 9; 2,000 gp):

> Provided that you and your called armor or shield are on the same plane, you can call it to you by speaking the proper command word, regardless of the intervening distance. If you aren't wearing armor at the time, a suit of called armor appears on your body, as though you had donned it in the normal fashion. If you are wearing other armor when you speak the command word, the called armor appears in your space or in an adjacent space you designate that is capable of holding it. A called shield appears on the proper arm if you are not already using another shield when you call it, or in your space or a designated adjacent space if you are.
>
> If any other creature has worn your called armor or shield since you last wore it, you can no longer call it until you wear it again.

Your DM may be willing to allow you to apply the Enhancement to a weapon; otherwise you could always dual-wield shields...

**Disarming Enhancement**

The *Disarming* Weapon Enhancement (MIC, p. 32; +2 bonus) is quite expensive, but gives blanket immunity versus disarming:

> A disarming weapon grants you a +2 bonus on disarm attempts. In addition, opponents
> cannot disarm you of this weapon.

I would not recommend it; and just mentioned it for completion.

---

I would note here that disarming is only *one* of several options that your opponents have to cause you to drop your weapon. If you lose consciousness, or are stunned, you will also drop anything you are holding.

As a result, I would discourage you from focusing too much on *Disarm* specifically and instead consider the broader issue.

One approach you could consider, for example, is mixing strategies:

- 1 *Locked Gauntlet*, for your primary weapon.
- 1 *Crystal of Return, Lesser*, for your secondary weapon.

Using a single *Locked Gauntlet* means that you can lock/unlock it by yourself, as well as leaving you with a free hand to perform various tasks (such as opening a door...).

If you are stunned, you'll drop your secondary weapon to the ground, but can continue fighting with a single weapon, and pick it up later. Or just use your Move Action to summon it back and attack with a Standard Action. Or Quick Draw<sup>1</sup> another weapon before Full Attacking, since you likely other weapons at hand: Dagger? Shiftsilver Morningstar (vs DR/silver, DR/bludgeoning and DR/piercing)? Or... simply use an Unarmed Attack with your Spiked Gauntlet.

Finally, be wary of not over-reacting. In this case, I think it makes sense to invest some resources in ensuring that you always have a good weapon at hand; in general though, over-reacting after a single bad experience may waste your limited resources.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Consider the Glove of the Master Strategist (Ghostwalk, p. 71; 3,600 gp) or the Cloak of Weaponry (MIC, p. 89; 2,300 gp) if you do not have the feat.*

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer - especially the *alternaitives* section is very helpful!

Comment: @Giorin: You're welcome :) I love melee characters, so losing my character's weapon has always been an issue.

Answer (score 4):

The rules are silent about using a pair of locked gauntlets. They do give the amount of time it takes to lock or unlock one, however, it doesn't indicate if you have to have help or not.

Given that the gauntlet prevents use of that hand for what seems everything but weapon use while locked, it would seem unlikely that a character would be able to put on a second locked gauntlet themselves, let alone take one off once you have both on.

There is nothing preventing it, but there are no specific rules about it.

I would highly recommend that you have a means of taking it off yourself, be it a magic item, or something, just in case.

Maybe you could convince your DM to allow a custom locked gauntlet with an animate object effect on it that allows it to unlock and lock itself on command.

Answer (score 1):

The [rules](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Locked_Gauntlets) state "While the gauntlet is locked, you can’t use the hand wearing it for casting spells or employing skills." Whether this prvents you from locing and unlocking another gauntlet with an already locked gauntlet is up to your DM.

That's why knights had [squires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squire).